# R Data frame - converting letters to numbers.

Tags: r, optimization, dataframe

I have a data frame with +200,000 lines and converting letters into numbers in one of the columns (18 columns in total).

Extract is my df and the column in question is Route_IATA. My code is

```
extract$Route_IATA <- lapply
(extract$Route_IATA, function(x) gsubfn('(.)', as.list(v1), toupper(as.character(x))))
```

The system.time returns **143 sec** that is not only slow but it would get worse with more records added. My question is: are there any other options in R to speed up the process?

Comment: maybe I miss something, but why can't you do `extract$Route_IATA <- as.numeric(extract$Route_IATA)` ?

Comment: also you may want add a call `library(gsubfn)` at the start of your example to signal you're using it, and tell us what `v1` is

Comment: Thanks but the value is built like AA1234 where AA represents any letter/number combination and 1234 is the number. So the idea is to change AA1234 to 111234. library(gsubfn) is indeed included.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a loop over all values (`lapply`), which is not needed here. This is a reason it takes so long.

The argument `x` can be a vector in the function `gsubfn`. So this should be much faster. I have not tested it.

```
extract$Route_IATA <- gsubfn('(.)', as.list(v1), toupper(as.character(extract$Route_IATA)))
```

Comment: Interesting but the the original code gives 143.01 sec elapsed time  and yours 158.01 sec.